# tamper proof embedded microprocessor

Tags: embedded, reverse-engineering

I develop commercially embedded hardware, using Microchip dsPIC or similar processors.

The firmware I have is sometimes very complex and costly, and needs to be hacker and tamper proof in hardware. All basic software protections are there, but for $500 - $1,000 the hex code can be retrieved via several foreign website services, even if there are security fuses (preventing only not-determined tampering).
After that, it is just a few months and the code can be reverse-engineered using disassembler, like IDA Pro.

How can I protect the hardware design a bit better (no need for military protection)?

Can you recommend another non-readable processors, or perhaps an addition to my existing design?

All I need is to hide few functions, I do not need the whole product. Also, it is not enough just to hide data in secure external memory, I need to hide a piece of program.

Update (based on many comments):
I have dsPIC and 4 full-time years of development on firmware (would take quite an effort to do it from scratch another way):

1) This product already sells and hackers have access if they want to

2) The NEW FIRMWARE is not released yet. Contains 5kB code which no-one from all competition has yet. I need to prevent anyone easily getting it for about 12 months after the release

3) There is no budget to go very exotic or complicated, maybe additional $10 per product, plus or minus

4) A solution like added SIM card might do the trick?

5) The function to hide does very tricky calculation, non-standard, to decrypt/encrypt 16 bytes. Known processes cannot hack it in 1 year, the function is needed, which is why I want to hide it.

6) I do not mind if it is publicly visible, when the request is sent to 'hidden' hardware, or if the response is publicly visible. Only need to hide the process calculating it, and cannot be inside the dsPIC processor.

Comment: First rule of security - never talk about security. My advice would be to **hire** a specialist in processor security rather than ask on a public site.

Comment: Jim: A good one. Still, I am looking for a concept, not a solution. I am a reverse-engineer myself, and anything on basic CPUs I can reverse-engineer - I am looking for prevention, or to make it harder, but not in the style of potting it into epoxy or such (that delays it only 1 day)

Comment: Some microprocessors have a security fuse that prevents read-out of code.  Google `MSP430 security fuse` for an example.

Comment: user1831847: that doesn't really work, see the question and $1,000 ( I have witnessed it myself with my own secure code)

Comment: Then as you know its not that easy - even on microprocessors that are 'secure'. If you throw enough resources at it just about anything is crackable. At least if you hire a third party you can always sue them if it goes wrong ;)

Comment: Lawsuits... Tried many times. Doesn't stop the product copying, only cost HUGE without anyone winning. Plus the lawsuit only work in US/Canada, really.

Comment: @Jim Dearden 2nd rule, security by obscurity is no security. Hiring a specialist would be a good idea though. Guy.  Security is never absolute it always a factor of time and money can you give us a clue as to what level of protection you are looking for in these terms.

Comment: If you don't have something like online authentication I think you're pretty much SOL. As you say, it's cheap enough to break simple protections (they can remove the encapsulation and use various techniques to disable, bypass or rewire around protections if nothing easier works). You can try the security SE. If your product is any good it will get copied, and even if you could secure the firmware, how hard *really* would it be to rewrite it? A lot of the cost is in determining specs and so on that the copier doesn't need to do.

Comment: I think that more information about security criteria is needed. How acceptable is for the security systems to accidentally disable the product? How much can you invest into self-destruction systems? How many layers of security do you want? List goes on and on and on.

Comment: What about the various smartcard systems?

Comment: One way would be to use public key authentication and encrypt a piece of code. Then keep the decryption key stored in some very volatile memory that could erase itself if tampered. I've seen that done with FPGA firmwares. There are methods to detect if the box is being opened or if someone is working on the epoxy which could help. POS disassembly videos can give idea. Of course, for code, it's more complicated. If I remember correctly, PICs can't execute anything from data memory?

Comment: I updated the original question to address many comments above

Comment: Nice video about methods on [MSP430](http://www.securitytube.net/video/11878) and modern glossy from [TI](http://www.ti.com/lit/wp/slay035/slay035.pdf) about the subject.

Comment: Thank you video is nice. It basically shows why I worry. There is easier method though: pay $1,000 and almost any chip is read out for you (you receive a binary file). Because of that, I am looking to hide section of binary code, which means it cannot be programmed in any regular chip, security fuses are not stopping reading just making it very inconvenient.

Comment: If it is not built into the core of the chip, it should be fairly trivial, smart cards, etc.  Just going to feed unprotected instructions across an interface into an unprotected chip.

Comment: A few months?  Companies with the millions of dollars have their products hacked in hours.  They spend months to years to locking down to have them defeated the day of the release?  That is the general life span of security these days, with stock processors running unencrypted code over sniffable busses.

Comment: If all you know or want to know is Microchip dsPIC then you need to got microchip and see what they offer.  Most likely an OTP is your best bet, assuming it cannot be read, similar to what FPGAs or CPLDs do, or try to do.

Comment: You might want to take a look at this on cryptography. http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/43272/why-is-writing-your-own-encryption-discouraged

Comment: Adding a smartcard(sim card or any other shape ) is a way but not best approach for this case.
Smart card communicate via ISO7816 which is not a fast protocol,There are some high speed based Security authentication chips(e.g. AT97SC3205)
If you can change your processor,These is some MCU with built-in security feature,like LPC18Sxx & LPC43Sxx from NXP,STM32F423 from st,etc.
Also in some TI product like concerto famlily I have seen before  a security feature called ECSL & CSM which prevent from code reverse engineering.

Comment: You may want to look into *obfuscation* of your code. Doesn't prevent read out of the binary, but makes the binary harder to reverse.

Answer (score 1):

There is companies specializing on that. Atmelwas one of them, also inside secure. They habe special hardware that can suit your needs. But if you want it really work,be prepared to secure the whole chain from their asic warehouse to your production facility with vaults and guards for the security codes. Otherwise you will only make $1k for attempt $10k, while you actually need $1M at least.

Comment: I hear what you mean. $1M is okay if the product sells for $10M/year, which is not my case. But the Secure hardware without vaults and guards might suffice. I only need small type of CPU for this extra calculation security.

Comment: Then fire the guards :)

Comment: Based on your update- call inside secure.

Comment: Gregory: Sorry, i do not understand what do you mean by "inside secure"

Comment: https://www.insidesecure.com/

Comment: CAREFUL! The link to insidesecure was blocked by my antivirus as it was trying to install a trojan. False positive? Who knows? But this is the first time it's happened to me.

Comment: To me it didn't happen

Answer (score 1):

Researchers at MIT developed a way to scramble the code mathematically, but keep the output the same. The only way the function executes is if you give it the correct key, which could be downloaded from time to time.

This might be useful to you: http://spectrum.ieee.org/computing/software/scrambled-code-keeps-software-safe

Comment: While not yet practical solution, thank you for an interesting educational read.